# 12 month moving average from python

Tags: python, pandas

```py
df_close['MA'] = df_close.rolling(window=12).mean()
```

I keep getting this error can anyone help please

```
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 20, placement implies 1
```

My assignment:

1. Pull 20 years of monthly stock price and trading volume data for any 20 stocks of your pick from Yahoo Finance.
2. Calculate the monthly returns and 12-month moving average of each stock.

Other parts of the code:

````py
start = dt.datetime(2000,1,1)
end = dt.datetime(2020,2,1)

df = web.DataReader(['AAPL', 'MSFT', 'ROKU', 'GS', 'GOOG', 'KO', 'ULTA', 'JNJ', 'ZM', 'AMZN', 'NFLX', 'TSLA', 'CMG', 'ATVI', 'LOW', 'BA', 'SYY', 'SNAP', 'BYND', 'OSTK'], 'yahoo',start,end)

df['Adj Close']
df['Volume']

data1 = df[['Adj Close', 'Volume']].copy()
data1['date1'] = data1.index
print(data1)

data2 = data1.merge(data1, left_on='date1', right_on='date1')
data2

df.sort_index()
df

df_monthly_returns = df['Adj Close'].ffill().pct_change()
df_monthly_returns.sort_index()
print(df_monthly_returns.tail())

df_close['MA'] = df_close.rolling(window=12).mean()
df_close ```
````

Comment: Can you give more details? Like a sample of your dataframe and your desired output?

Comment: start = dt.datetime(2000,1,1)
end = dt.datetime(2020,2,1)

Comment: df = web.DataReader(['AAPL', 'MSFT', 'ROKU', 'GS', 'GOOG', 'KO', 'ULTA', 'JNJ', 'ZM', 'AMZN', 'NFLX', 'TSLA', 'CMG', 'ATVI', 'LOW', 'BA', 'SYY', 'SNAP', 'BYND', 'OSTK'], 'yahoo',start,end)
df.tail(100)

Comment: @ibrahimjaafil add the details on comments to question itself, edit your question

Comment: I pulled 20 years of monthly stock price and trading volume. I calculated the monthly returns but i couldn't calculate the moving average  it keeps giving me this error

Comment: Construct an equal-weighted portfolio of the 20 stocks and plot the time series of the portfolio returns and the time series of 12-month moving average of the portfolio returns.?  any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 20, placement implies 1 means that you are attempting to put too many elements in less space.

```
df_close['MA'] = df_close.rolling(window=12).mean()
```

You are pushing 20 "things" into a container that allows only one.

So if you want to put a element with 20 "columns" into a single dataframe column, try iterating over `df_close.rolling(window=12).mean()` and store in `df_close['MA']`.

And please update your question with more code so that I can give you a exact solution.

Comment: how can I construct an equal-weighted portfolio of the 20 stocks?